# Fiddler doesn't capture Apache HttpClient post

Tags: java, fiddler, apache-httpclient-4.x

Somehow Fiddler doesn't capture the posts I send from my HttpClient provided by Apache.

But when I send the same post in C# using the HttpClient to the same server, Fiddler does intercept the sessions.

My Java code:

```
private DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
private HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
private BasicCookieStore store = new BasicCookieStore();

public Client() throws URISyntaxException {
    context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, store);
    logIn();
}

private void logIn() throws URISyntaxException {
    HttpUriRequest login = RequestBuilder.post()
            .setUri(new URI("http://www.derpforum.nl"))
            .addParameter("username", "Kattoor4")
            .addParameter("password", "XXXX")
            .addHeader("Referer", "http://www.derpforum.nl/")
            .build();
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(login, context)) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am usring **Apache HttpClient(4.5.5), SWT4 and Fiddler4**, and the VM arguments method does not work for me.

So I set the proxy settings in the code and it works.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 8888, "http");
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure Java to use Fiddler as a proxy either in code or by setting the relevant Java system properties as below. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549749/how-to-capture-https-with-fiddler-in-java)

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
```