# How to use network proxy when connecting to Microsoft Azure Media Services

Tags: java, azure, proxy, azure-media-services, azure-java-sdk

When I run Microsoft Azure Media Services  code written using Java in local it is working but when I deploy the same code in dev environment , I am unable to access the Azure and its throwing java.net.HostNotFoundException.

What is the best approach to use network proxy to connect to Azure

Below is the code I am using via java and using azure-java-sdk

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.EnumSet;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.Configuration;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.MediaConfiguration;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.MediaContract;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.MediaService;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.WritableBlobContainerContract;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.AccessPolicy;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.AccessPolicyInfo;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.AccessPolicyPermission;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.Asset;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.AssetFile;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.AssetFileInfo;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.AssetInfo;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.Job;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.JobInfo;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.JobState;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.ListResult;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.Locator;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.LocatorInfo;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.LocatorType;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.MediaProcessor;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.MediaProcessorInfo;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.media.models.Task;


public class HelloMediaServices
{
    // Media Services account credentials configuration
    private static String mediaServiceUri = "https://media.windows.net/API/";
    private static String oAuthUri = "https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
    private static String clientId = "account name";
    private static String clientSecret = "account key";
    private static String scope = "urn:WindowsAzureMediaServices";
    private static MediaContract mediaService;

    // Encoder configuration
    private static String preferedEncoder = "Media Encoder Standard";
    private static String encodingPreset = "H264 Multiple Bitrate 720p";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try {
            // Set up the MediaContract object to call into the Media Services account
            Configuration configuration = MediaConfiguration.configureWithOAuthAuthentication(
            mediaServiceUri, oAuthUri, clientId, clientSecret, scope);
            mediaService = MediaService.create(configuration);


            // Upload a local file to an Asset
            AssetInfo uploadAsset = uploadFileAndCreateAsset("BigBuckBunny.mp4");
            System.out.println("Uploaded Asset Id: " + uploadAsset.getId());


            // Transform the Asset
            AssetInfo encodedAsset = encode(uploadAsset);
            System.out.println("Encoded Asset Id: " + encodedAsset.getId());

            // Create the Streaming Origin Locator
            String url = getStreamingOriginLocator(encodedAsset);

            System.out.println("Origin Locator URL: " + url);
            System.out.println("Sample completed!");

        } catch (ServiceException se) {
            System.out.println("ServiceException encountered.");
            System.out.println(se.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception encountered.");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    }

    private static AssetInfo uploadFileAndCreateAsset(String fileName)
        throws ServiceException, FileNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        WritableBlobContainerContract uploader;
        AssetInfo resultAsset;
        AccessPolicyInfo uploadAccessPolicy;
        LocatorInfo uploadLocator = null;

        // Create an Asset
        resultAsset = mediaService.create(Asset.create().setName(fileName).setAlternateId("altId"));
        System.out.println("Created Asset " + fileName);

        // Create an AccessPolicy that provides Write access for 15 minutes
        uploadAccessPolicy = mediaService
            .create(AccessPolicy.create("uploadAccessPolicy", 15.0, EnumSet.of(AccessPolicyPermission.WRITE)));

        // Create a Locator using the AccessPolicy and Asset
        uploadLocator = mediaService
            .create(Locator.create(uploadAccessPolicy.getId(), resultAsset.getId(), LocatorType.SAS));

        // Create the Blob Writer using the Locator
        uploader = mediaService.createBlobWriter(uploadLocator);

        File file = new File("BigBuckBunny.mp4"); 

        // The local file that will be uploaded to your Media Services account
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

        System.out.println("Uploading " + fileName);

        // Upload the local file to the asset
        uploader.createBlockBlob(fileName, input);

        // Inform Media Services about the uploaded files
        mediaService.action(AssetFile.createFileInfos(resultAsset.getId()));
        System.out.println("Uploaded Asset File " + fileName);

        mediaService.delete(Locator.delete(uploadLocator.getId()));
        mediaService.delete(AccessPolicy.delete(uploadAccessPolicy.getId()));

        return resultAsset;
    }

    // Create a Job that contains a Task to transform the Asset
    private static AssetInfo encode(AssetInfo assetToEncode)
        throws ServiceException, InterruptedException {

        // Retrieve the list of Media Processors that match the name
        ListResult<MediaProcessorInfo> mediaProcessors = mediaService
                        .list(MediaProcessor.list().set("$filter", String.format("Name eq '%s'", preferedEncoder)));

        // Use the latest version of the Media Processor
        MediaProcessorInfo mediaProcessor = null;
        for (MediaProcessorInfo info : mediaProcessors) {
            if (null == mediaProcessor || info.getVersion().compareTo(mediaProcessor.getVersion()) > 0) {
                mediaProcessor = info;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Using Media Processor: " + mediaProcessor.getName() + " " + mediaProcessor.getVersion());

        // Create a task with the specified Media Processor
        String outputAssetName = String.format("%s as %s", assetToEncode.getName(), encodingPreset);
        String taskXml = "<taskBody><inputAsset>JobInputAsset(0)</inputAsset>"
                + "<outputAsset assetCreationOptions=\"0\"" // AssetCreationOptions.None
                + " assetName=\"" + outputAssetName + "\">JobOutputAsset(0)</outputAsset></taskBody>";

        Task.CreateBatchOperation task = Task.create(mediaProcessor.getId(), taskXml)
                .setConfiguration(encodingPreset).setName("Encoding");

        // Create the Job; this automatically schedules and runs it.
        Job.Creator jobCreator = Job.create()
                .setName(String.format("Encoding %s to %s", assetToEncode.getName(), encodingPreset))
                .addInputMediaAsset(assetToEncode.getId()).setPriority(2).addTaskCreator(task);
        JobInfo job = mediaService.create(jobCreator);

        String jobId = job.getId();
        System.out.println("Created Job with Id: " + jobId);

        // Check to see if the Job has completed
        checkJobStatus(jobId);
        // Done with the Job

        // Retrieve the output Asset
        ListResult<AssetInfo> outputAssets = mediaService.list(Asset.list(job.getOutputAssetsLink()));
        return outputAssets.get(0);
    }


    public static String getStreamingOriginLocator(AssetInfo asset) throws ServiceException {
        // Get the .ISM AssetFile
        ListResult<AssetFileInfo> assetFiles = mediaService.list(AssetFile.list(asset.getAssetFilesLink()));
        AssetFileInfo streamingAssetFile = null;
        for (AssetFileInfo file : assetFiles) {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".ism")) {
                streamingAssetFile = file;
                break;
            }
        }

        AccessPolicyInfo originAccessPolicy;
        LocatorInfo originLocator = null;

        // Create a 30-day readonly AccessPolicy
        double durationInMinutes = 60 * 24 * 30;
        originAccessPolicy = mediaService.create(
                AccessPolicy.create("Streaming policy", durationInMinutes, EnumSet.of(AccessPolicyPermission.READ)));

        // Create a Locator using the AccessPolicy and Asset
        originLocator = mediaService
                .create(Locator.create(originAccessPolicy.getId(), asset.getId(), LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin));

        // Create a Smooth Streaming base URL
        return originLocator.getPath() + streamingAssetFile.getName() + "/manifest";
    }

    private static void checkJobStatus(String jobId) throws InterruptedException, ServiceException {
        boolean done = false;
        JobState jobState = null;
        while (!done) {
            // Sleep for 5 seconds
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            // Query the updated Job state
            jobState = mediaService.get(Job.get(jobId)).getState();
            System.out.println("Job state: " + jobState);

            if (jobState == JobState.Finished || jobState == JobState.Canceled || jobState == JobState.Error) {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share your code. We don't know if you're consuming REST API directly or using some SDK.

Comment: @GauravMantri Added the java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who face issue like me we can connect to azure mediaservices using network proxy by using below code

```
 // Set up the MediaContract object to call into the Media Services account
  Configuration configuration = MediaConfiguration.configureWithOAuthAuthentication(
                    mediaServiceUri, oAuthUri, clientId, clientSecret, scope);
  configuration.getProperties().put(Configuration.PROPERTY_HTTP_PROXY_HOST, "Hostvalue");
  configuration.getProperties().put(Configuration.PROPERTY_HTTP_PROXY_PORT, "Portvalue");
  configuration.getProperties().put(Configuration.PROPERTY_HTTP_PROXY_SCHEME, "http");
  MediaContract mediaService = MediaService.create(configuration);
```

Now use the mediaService to perform other operations.

Answer (score 1):

I verified following code below which is working through fiddler proxy. Thanks to [how to Capture https with fiddler, in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549749/how-to-capture-https-with-fiddler-in-java) post which gave me hints:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_102\\bin\\FiddlerKeyStore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "mypassword");
```

Comment: We are using azure-media 0.9.4 and when I did the above I got below error                                 com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.UnknownHostException: ams-usso-1-hos-rest-1-1.cloudapp.net]

Comment: i updated sample to use System.setProperty and verified that code is working through fiddler. Probably your proxy server has problem resolving ams-usso-1-hos-rest-1-1.cloudapp.net. this rest endpoint is available and returns response. https://ams-usso-1-hos-rest-1-1.cloudapp.net/api/$metadata?api-version=2.13

Comment: @rajadilipkolli, I doubt the `java.net.UnknownHostException` issue was caused by your network environment. Please check your DNS setting in the dev environment, and inspect whether can access some host via IP, but failed via domain name.