# How do I hook up Charles with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, proxy, charles-proxy

I am writing a web application in Java using [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), and I would like to monitor all my http/https requests using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), however my requests do not show up by default, so I am suspecting that some proxy settings need to be set up on both sides. Can someone explain it in details?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what http requests? From intellij idea itself, or your app?

Comment: I'd like to monitor requests made by my app. However as I only need this for testing purposes, I'd prefer to set up these proxy configurations in IntelliJ, and not in the project itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok so, I have managed to understand the problem and also solve it.

### JVM proxy

The first issue was that my requests were essentially coming from the JVM, so that's why we have to proxy them first, which means a JVM configuration has to be made, which can be provided as arguments (can be provided through CLI or under **VM options** in IntelliJ) like so:

`-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888`

### HTTPS

The next issue was that along with this proxy, **certificates also have to be provided** in order to capture and view decrypted https requests.

We can generate Fiddler certificates by going to *Tools > Options > HTTPS > Decrypt HTTPS traffic*. The generated cert can be downloaded from http://127.0.0.1:8888/.

Using JVM's keytool, we can create a new keystore using our certificate, which we can use later as a JVM configuration to trust resources. To do so, run the following command (make sure to provide the right paths for the keytool and the cert):

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\keytool.exe -import -file C:\Users\Username\Desktop\FiddlerRoot.cer -keystore FiddlerKeystore -alias Fiddler`

After providing a password, the keystore will be generated at `C:\Windows\System32`.

Now, we can provide this keystore and password to the JVM by passing the following:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Windows\System32\FiddlerKeystore" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="yourKeyStorePassword"`

This answer was based on the following blog post and StackOverflow answer:

- [Capture HTTPS traffic from Java applications with Fiddler](http://dharampal.in/2013/07/03/capture-https-traffic-from-java-applications-with-fiddler/)
- [How to Capture https with fiddler, in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549749/how-to-capture-https-with-fiddler-in-java/8588914#8588914)

Comment: This works the same with Charles Proxy: set the JVM proxying (`-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888`), then install the Charles Certificates in Charles > Help > SSL Proxying > Instal Charles Root Certificate.

Comment: I didn't find the keystore generated at `C:\Windows\System32`... is it possible that it's generated to somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Following these directions on the official site:

https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

1. Export the Charles Proxy root certificate.
2. Install the certificate into the JVM certificate store for the Java version that your application in IntelliJ is using.

   sudo keytool -import -alias charles -file ~/Desktop/charles-ssl-proxying-certificate.pem

The issue I had was that the IntelliJ run 'configuration' (for running the Java application from inside IntelliJ) was using a different SDK to the actual Project level SDK.

Go to Edit Configurations in IntelliJ to confirm the SDK being used at runtime.

Edit: I also found that some libraries (sp. Apache HttpClient) bypass the configure SDK/Proxy settings, leading to requests from IntelliJ that are not visible to Charles Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Charles has already supported JVM proxy. So all you have to do is:

1. install certificate for jvm;
2. set jvm proxy;

I will describe the details below:

**1 install certificate for jvm**

This can be done by:

> Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate In Java VMs

show as the below picture:
[image]

Note that Charles use 8888 port by default, if your proxy port is not 8888, just input your own proxy port.

**2 set jvm proxy**

You can set jvm proxy by two ways, java code or program arguments,
show as the below code:

```
// method 1: use the java code
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
 
// method 2：use the program arguments
-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888
```

Comment: in Charles v4.5.6. under Help -> SSL Proxying,there is no "Install Charles Root Certificate In Java VMs" option

Comment: I am using Charles v4.2.8（as shown in the image above），and there is a "Install Charles Root Certificate In Java VMs" option。 Maybe it is a version problem ?