# using fiddler with a java soap application call throws SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, soap, fiddler

I have setup fiddler to decrypt HTTPS traffic in the usual way.

[image]

My java application successfully calls the web service without fiddler.
Once I set the proxy, and make calls, I get the following exception.

I have set the proxy in my spring boot application as follows:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide fiddler`s certificate to your jvm keystore. here its explained [how to Capture https with fiddler, in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549749/how-to-capture-https-with-fiddler-in-java)